# Как возвести число в отрицательную степень

Tags: python

```
def pow (a, n):
    res = 1
    for i in range(0, n):
        res *= a
    if n >=0:
        return res
    else:
        return 1/res

print(pow(3, -1))
```

Comment: во-первых, отформатируйте свой код. во-вторых, текст вопроса где? Или вы сегодня решили быть особо загадочным и задать второй вопрос так, чтобы никто ничего не понял?

Comment: нужно возвести в положительную и поделить единицу на результат

Comment: Табуляцию во второй строке я за вас поправил

Comment: Хочу просто уточнить, а чем `a**n` не устраивает?

Answer (score 0):

Одну строчку надо поменять, чтобы `range` смог отработать при отрицательном `n` задуманным вами образом:

```
for i in range(0, abs(n)):
                  ^^^^^^
```

Результат:

```
0.3333333333333333
```